# Concentus: Distorted audio after decoding and mixed

Tags: c#, naudio, opus

I have made a simple VOIP group chat that works perfectly when there is no encoder/decoder however as soon as I implement a codec and have it mixing multiple decoded audio streams then there is a ton of noise. If it's just 1 on 1 talking then there is no noise.

This is what I tried.
Currently I am recording at 48khz 40ms 16bit Mono audio and encoding with the concentus lib. Code Below... (BytesToShorts and ShortsToBytes methods are direct copies from the demo of the concentus lib)

```cs
private void AudioDataAvailable(object? sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsDeafened || IsMuted)
                return;

            float max = 0;
            // interpret as 16 bit audio
            for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2)
            {
                short sample = (short)((e.Buffer[index + 1] << 8) |
                                        e.Buffer[index + 0]);
                // to floating point
                var sample32 = sample / 32768f;
                // absolute value 
                if (sample32 < 0) sample32 = -sample32;
                if (sample32 > max) max = sample32;
            }

            if (max > 0.08)
            {
                RecordDetection = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }

            if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(RecordDetection).Seconds < 1)
            {
                short[] pcm = BytesToShorts(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                byte[] encoded = new byte[1000];
                Encoder.Encode(pcm, 0, 960, encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
                var voicePacket = new VoicePacket()
                {
                    PacketAudio = encoded,
                    PacketDataIdentifier = PacketIdentifier.Audio,
                    PacketVersion = Network.Network.Version,
                    PacketBytesRecorded = e.BytesRecorded
                };
                VCClient.Send(voicePacket);
            }
        }
```

Then on the decode side I do this...

```cs
private Task VC_OnAudioReceived(byte[] Audio, string Key, float Volume, int BytesRecorded, float RotationSource)
        {
            _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var participant = Participants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginKey == Key);
                if (participant != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        short[] decoded = new short[960];
                        Decoder.Decode(Audio, 0, Audio.Length, decoded, 0, 960, false);
                        byte[] decodedBytes = ShortsToBytes(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
                        participant.FloatProvider.Volume = Volume;
                        if (DirectionalAudio)
                        {
                            participant.MonoToStereo.LeftVolume = (float)(0.5 + Math.Sin(RotationSource) * 0.5);
                            participant.MonoToStereo.RightVolume = (float)(0.5 - Math.Sin(RotationSource) * 0.5);
                        }
                        participant.WaveProvider.AddSamples(decodedBytes, 0, BytesRecorded);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            });

            if(!Stopping && AudioPlayer.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
                AudioPlayer.Play();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

participant variable consists of

```cs
public class ParticipantModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; } = "";
   public string LoginKey { get; set; } = "";
   public BufferedWaveProvider WaveProvider { get; set; }
   public Wave16ToFloatProvider FloatProvider { get; set; }
   public MonoToStereoSampleProvider MonoToStereo { get; set; }
}
```

and is created like so...

```cs
case VCSignalling_Packet.PacketIdentifier.Login:
   var participant = new ParticipantModel()
   {
      LoginKey = packet.PacketLoginKey,
      Name = packet.PacketName,
      WaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(VoipService.GetRecordFormat) { DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true }
   };
   participant.FloatProvider = new Wave16ToFloatProvider(participant.WaveProvider);
   participant.MonoToStereo = new NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders.MonoToStereoSampleProvider(participant.FloatProvider.ToSampleProvider());

   OnParticipantLogin?.Invoke(participant);
   break;
```

Record and Playback formats

```cs
public static WaveFormat GetRecordFormat { get => new WaveFormat(SampleRate, 16, Channels); }
public static WaveFormat GetAudioFormat { get => WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(SampleRate, Channels * 2); }
```

Opus encoder and decoder initializations.

```cs
Encoder = new OpusEncoder(SampleRate, Channels, Concentus.Enums.OpusApplication.OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP);
Encoder.Complexity = 0;
Encoder.UseVBR = true;

Decoder = new OpusDecoder(SampleRate, Channels);
```

Mixer, Recorder and AudioPlayer

```cs
Mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(GetAudioFormat);
Normalizer = new SoftLimiter(Mixer);
Normalizer.Boost.CurrentValue = 5;

AudioRecorder = audioManager.CreateRecorder(GetRecordFormat);
AudioPlayer = audioManager.CreatePlayer(Normalizer);
```

Softlimiter class taken and implemented from https://www.markheath.net/post/limit-audio-naudio

I have isolated that the problem is the codec. When doing everything without compressing the audio. Everything is clear and working fine with 3-5+ people talking at the same time. As soon as the codec or **A** codec is implemented then the mixing of audio with 2 people talking at the same time just gets distorted and crackly. (I've tried to use g722 codec before).

I know there is some loss going on with decoder but I did not expect it to fully affect mixing. What is going on and what can I do to fix it? Would I have to do audio cleaning or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's one of those moments again where you ask a question then a day later you try something and it works...

Alright so I figured out why there are tons of distortions when there are 2 people talking at the same time with an audio codec in the middle. What I had to do was change it so there is a decoder per connected client on the client side. So what I did was modify both snippets below...

```cs
public class ParticipantModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string LoginKey { get; set; } = "";
    public BufferedWaveProvider WaveProvider { get; set; }
    public Wave16ToFloatProvider FloatProvider { get; set; }
    public MonoToStereoSampleProvider MonoToStereo { get; set; }
    public OpusDecoder Decoder { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
private Task VC_OnAudioReceived(byte[] Audio, string Key, float Volume, int BytesRecorded, float RotationSource)
        {
            _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var participant = Participants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginKey == Key);
                if (participant != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        short[] decoded = new short[960];
                        participant.Decoder.Decode(Audio, 0, Audio.Length, decoded, 0, decoded.Length, false);
                        byte[] decodedBytes = ShortsToBytes(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
                        participant.FloatProvider.Volume = Volume;
                        if (DirectionalAudio)
                        {
                            participant.MonoToStereo.LeftVolume = (float)(0.5 + Math.Sin(RotationSource) * 0.5);
                            participant.MonoToStereo.RightVolume = (float)(0.5 - Math.Sin(RotationSource) * 0.5);
                        }
                        participant.WaveProvider.AddSamples(decodedBytes, 0, BytesRecorded);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            });
```

After this I came to the conclusion that audio codecs work on a per stream basis and do not independently decode each individual sample.